# Haskell groupBy function: How exactly does it work?

Tags: haskell

I experienced the following behavior:

```
ghci :m +Data.List

ghci> groupBy (\x y -> succ x == y) [1..6]
[[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
ghci> groupBy (\x y -> succ x /= y) [1..6]
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]

ghci :m +Data.Char   -- just a test to verify that nothing is broken with my ghc

ghci> groupBy (const isAlphaNum) "split this"
["split"," this"]
```

which surprised me, I thought, based on the example down below, that `groupBy` splits a list whenever the predicate evaluates to `True` for two successive elements supplied to a predicate. But in my second example above it splits the list on every element, but the predicate should evaluate to `False`. I framed my assumption of how it works in Haskell as well, just so everybody understands how I believed it to work:

```
groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupBy p l@(x:y:ys)
  | p x y     = (x:y:(head l)) ++ (tail l)       -- assuming l has a tail, unwilling to
  | otherwise = [x] ++ (y:(head l)) ++ (tail l)  -- to debug this right now, I guess you
groupBy _ [x] = [[x]]                            -- already got the hang of it ;)
```

Which brought me to the conclusion, that it works somewhat different. So my question is, how does that function actually work?

Comment: The definition of `groupBy` in the standard library assumes that the given function is an equivalence relation; if that isn't the case (it isn't for any of the three functions you've used) then `groupBy` won't work as the documentation claims (or, if it does, it's pure coincidence).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> But in my second example above it splits the list on every element, but the predicate should evaluate to `False`.

In the second example it *also* evaluates every two consecutive elements. The function on which it works is `const isAlphaNum`. So that means that the type is:

```
const isAlphaNum :: b -> Char -> Bool
```

It thus *calls* the function with the beginning of the group and the element, but it takes *only the second element into account*.

So if we call it with: `groupBy (const isAlphaNum) "split this"`, it will evaluate:

```
succs   2nd    const isAlphaNum
-------------------------------
"sp"    'p'    True
"sl"    'l'    True
"si"    'i'    True
"st"    't'    True
"s "    ' '    False
" t"    't'    True
" h"    'h'    True
" i"    'i'    True
" s"    's'    True
```

Every time `const isAlphaNum` is `True`, it will append the character to the current sequence. So in case we evaluate `"t "`, `const isAlphaNum`, it will evaluate to `False`, `groupBy` will start a new group.

So here we thus construct two groups since there is only one `False`.

We can also obtain this result if we analyze the function [source code](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#groupBy):

> ```
> groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
> groupBy _  []     =  []
> groupBy eq (x:xs) =  (x:ys) : groupBy eq zs
>     where (ys,zs) = span (eq x) xs
> ```

So here `groupBy` will return the empty list if the given list is empty. In case it is not an empty list `(x:xs)` then we will construct a new sequence. The sequence starts with `x`, and contains furthermore all the elements of `ys`. `ys` is the first element of the 2-tuple constructed by `span`.

`span :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])` constructs a 2-tuple where the first element is the longest possible prefix of the list that satisfies the predicate, the predicate here is `eq x` so we keep adding elements to the group, as long as `eq x y` (with `y` an element) holds.

With the remaining part of the list `ys`, we construct a new group until the input is completely exhausted.